# du -hs results not adding up

Tags: linux, disk-usage

My computer complained about `no space left on device`.
I used `du -hs * | sort -h` to identify the biggest folders and kept going down the tree. I then found multiple directories I've been recently scp-ing to, all following this patten:

```
(base) user@computer:pathtodir$ du -hs
3.4G    .
(base) user@computer:pathtodir$ du * -hs
217M    checkpoint.pth.tar
127K    code
835     log.txt
```

From what I understand, these numbers should be adding to the same, yet there are 3.1G missing. I do not expect much to be within the code folder nor other files. The checkpoint.pth.tar file has been scp-ed with multiple versions on top of each other.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, I was missing the dotfiles, I should have also done `du -hs .[^.]*` instead to find them.

Comment: ... or `shopt -s dotglob` followed by your original `du -hs *` (note that options come before operands).